# Getting a random record from a Rails grouped query query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a model which I have around 250k instances stored. If I want to get a random instance, it's simple to do the following:

```
rand_offset = Random.new.rand(Model.count)
model = Model.limit(1).offset(rand_offset)
```

This works great, the random offset resolves to a quick COUNT(*) SQL query.

However, I also want to grab a random record which involves a group clause, something like:

```
rand_offset = Random.new.rand(Model.group(:field).having("COUNT(*)>?", minimum).count.count)
model = Model.group(:field).having("COUNT(*)>?", minimum).limit(1).offset(rand_offset)
```

This is significantly slower since instead of doing a SELECT COUNT(*) on the grouped subquery to find the random offset, it returns every single record matching that query and then returns the count of that array before randomizing it. This is giving me some noticeable slowness when it returns hundreds of thousands of results. Is there any way to speed this up without resorting to writing straight SQL?

Comment: I am not an expert on this stuff, but does it speed it up at all to store `Model.group(:field).having("COUNT(*)>?", minimum)` in a variable?

Comment: That would be faster, but I'm trying to avoid creating that array entirely since it involves loading potentially hundreds of thousands of records into an array when all I want is to load one. I'd rather get the count in one statement, then load one record based on that count.